# Show that this system has at least one unbounded solution as $t \to \infty$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, quadratics, periodic-functions, stability-in-odes

Assume the system
$$x'(t)=\begin{pmatrix} \frac12-\cos t & 2 \\ 1 & \frac32+\sin t \end{pmatrix}x(t)=A(t)\cdot x(t)$$
with minimum period: $T=2\pi$.

Let $\mu_1,\mu_2$ be its characteristic values. Then, a known theorem gives:
$$\mu_1\mu_2=\exp\Bigg\{\int_0^{2\pi} tr(A(t))dt\Bigg\} 
\iff \mu_1\mu_2=e^{4\pi}
$$

Therefore, $\mu_1,\mu_2$ are solutions of a quadratic equation of real coefficients that has the form:
$$
\mu^2-\varphi\mu+e^{4\pi}=0 \quad (1)
$$

For at least one solution to be unbounded, the discriminant of $(1)$ must be non-negative.
$$
\Delta=\varphi^2-4e^{4\pi} \geq 0 \iff |\varphi|\geq 2e^{2\pi}$$

How can I show that this condition for $\varphi$ is satisfied?

Comment: Why do you need anything about the discriminant? You have already shown that the Wronskian of any two linearly independent solutions is multiplied by $e^{4\pi}$ once we go over the period, so it grows exponentially meaning that at least one solution is unbounded.

Comment: @fedja What exactly do you mean by "multiplied by"? Can you elaborate on this part?

Comment: $W(t+2\pi)=e^{4\pi}W(t)$ for every $t$.